# Image Recognition using Python

Tags: python, image-recognition

I have an idea, that is, I want to identify the letters in an image which may be .bmp or .jpg.

For example, here is an .bmp image with a letter 'S' in it. What I want to do is to identify the letter using Python.

[image]

It's kinda similar with those Questions about `auth code recognition`, and I read some of those Q's, but still can't figure what to do.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) toolkit; it is commonly used for tasks where software must "recognize" some contents or features from images.

Answer (score 5):

Also there is whole blown system [Ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) which has Python bindings or perhaps better [Python bindings to tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/)